# How to catch everything between two (numbered) markers, including line breaks?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to capture everything between two markers (`START[number]` and `END[number]`) where number also needs to be extracted. I need to support line breaks.

For instance the following :

```
START[1] 
message to capture ...END[1]
```

must return :

1. group 1 : `1`
2. group 2 :
    
    `message to capture ...`
3. group 3 : `1`

Here is my attempt ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/FsaS5e/1)):

```
START\[(\d+)\]((.|\n|\r)*?)END\[(\d+)\]
```

It doesn't work as I obtain a third group made of the last character of the message to capture and I don't know why.

Can someone may help me with this ? Thanks.

Comment: You simply have too many capturing groups. Use a non-capturing group inside: `START\[(\d+)\]((?:.|\n|\r)*?)END\[(\d+)\]`

Comment: NEVER use `(.|\n|\r)*?`. Use dedicated patterns to match any char, like `[^]` in JS. Or a workaround like `[\s\S]`  / `[\d\D]` / `[\w\W]`

Comment: It's true, that `(.|\n|\r)*?` is not a good way to handle things, e.g. `[\s\S]` or the dotall flag `s` (not widely supported yet) are better solutions, however, i feel like the problem stems from using brackets, when a capturing group is not intended, and not using a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[\s\S]` instead of `(.|\n|\r)`

```
START\[(\d+)\]([\s\S]+?)END\[(\d+)\]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FsaS5e/2)

To be sure to have the same number in START and END, use a backreference to group 1:

(Credit to Aaron de Windt in comment)

```
START\[(\d+)\]([\s\S]+?)END\[(\1)\]
```

Comment: You can also swap the second "(\d+)" with a "\1" so it only matches if the two number are the same. "START\[(\d+)\]([\s\S]+?)END\[\1\]"